# laravel5 NotFoundHttpException

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am very new to Laravel and followed [this tutorial](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals/episodes/3) for the startup.

As in the tutorial, i have

```
Route::get("contact","WelcomeController@contact");
```

and in the Welcomecontroller I have a contact method:

```
public function contact()
    {
    return "Contact page";
    }
```

But accessing the page `http://localhost/laravel.dev/contact` throws me `NotFoundHttpException in D:\wamp\www\laravel\vendor\compiled.php line 7693:`

What could be the reason behind this? Is there something to do with setting or installtion path?

Answer (score 0):

I'd try two things:

1. Make sure you use the same cases for controller class name and route declaration (WelcomeController might not be equal to Welcomecontroller).
2. Go to your project base dir and run "php artisan clear-compiled" to make sure your Laravel "recompiles" everything and your compiled.php file includes the ControllerClass your route is expecting.

Answer (score 0):

More things to check:

Question first: When you setup Laravel, did you test the installation to see that it worked?  Or is this the first route you have tested?

If this is the very first route you have tested, maybe you have not set up the htaccess properly.  See here: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2#pretty-urls

You need to have mod_rewrite enabled.

Otherwise:

1) Check to make sure that inside WelcomeController.php you have named your class WelcomeController (if you were copying an existing example, you may not have remembered to rename the class)

2) Like MaGnetas answered, make sure that in ALL instances, you have used the same spelling and same lower/upper case for "WelcomeController"  (inside the routes, inside your class, anywhere you reference it.